# Adjusting for time in the COVID pandemic in survival analysis of time to treatment interruption

Tags: data-structures, survival-analysis

I am using a Cox model to evaluate associations of covariates with time to first treatment interruption after starting treatment. I have included a time-varying covariate called 'pivotal events', which notes whether people develop certain conditions or are hospitalised during their follow-up time (which may affect their engagement in care and increase the hazard of interruptions).
I want to include time in the COVID pandemic as a time-varying covariate. Because each individual's treatment initation date is different, the point at which COVID lockdowns etc affect them is different.
My univariate Cox model in R is:
cox_mod_time_inpandemic  <- coxph(Surv(tstart2, tstop2, status) ~ time_inpandemic , data = survival_1stgap_tvc)

**My question is: have I structured the data correctly?**
I am worried I have misunderstood how to code whether each time period is in or out of the pandemic. e.g. if the pandemic ends before the event of interest, so time_inpandemic is coded 0 when the event occurs/individual is censored, does the model consider that previous time periods WERE in the pandemic?

I have created time periods before the pandemic started, time periods during the pandemic, and time periods after the pandemic. Pivotal events and the primary outcome (a treatment interruption) can occur in any of these periods.
The dataframe looks like this:
[DATA STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdNwB.jpg)
Legend:
_id = individual identifier
event_type = pre_pandemic (pandemic starts at teh end of this time period), in_pandemic (tstop2 is the end of the pandemic so subsequent time periods are then out of the pandemic again), pivotal event, 1stgap (the primary end point) or censored (no gap occured)
tstart2 = start time of each time period
tstop2 = end of each time period
status = 1~ had a treatment interruption at the end of the period, 0 ~ no treatment interruption
pivotal_event_status = 1 if pivotal event had occured by the start of that period (i.e. occured at the end of the previous period of time, labelled event_type="pivotal_event"). This is carried over for subsequent time periods
**time_inpandemic** = whether that period was in the pandemic (1) or not (0). i.e. pre_pandemic will be out of the pandemic. All subsequent time periods are in the pandemic until the end of a time period called in_pandemic. so if a pivotal event/ gap occurs before 'pre_pandemic' they occured before the pandemic started. if there is no 'in_pandemic' for an individual it means that the last event occured before the pandemic ended.
pandemic_start and _end are just for reference, to denote the starting and ending point of the pandemic in relation to that individual's follow-up time since treatment was initated